# How to add a commented line with relative path to the first line of vim file

Tags: django, bash, shell, vim, comments

I am making a Django web app using Vim, and I want to add a commented line to the top of each file, I open or create, with its relative path.

For example: `# config/urls.py`, using `c-r` and `c-%` for its relative path.

So far I've been working on this bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter file name"
read newfile

if [[ $newfile = *.py ]]; then
    `touch $newfile && echo "# $PWD"/"$newfile">>$newfile`
    vim $newfile;
elif [[ $newfile = *.html ]]; then
    `touch $newfile && echo "<!-- $PWD"/"$newfile -->">>$newfile`
    vim $newfile;
elif [[ $newfile = *.css ]]; then
    `touch $newfile && echo "/* $PWD"/"$newfile */">>$newfile`
    vim $newfile;

else
    vim $newfile
fi
```

That opens with `# /home/menashe/testdir/test1.py`.

1. How do I only add the relative path `testdir/test1.py`?
2. Is it possible to put the Vim commands in the script?
3. How do I append a comment to the first line of a file that isn't empty?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about just putting something like this in your .vimrc:

```
augroup python_stuff
    autocmd!
    " Note that there is a single space after the #
    autocmd BufNewFile *.py :norm "%pI# 
augroup END
```

This will perform the normal mode commands anytime you open a new python file
in vim. You can make more augroups for other filetypes.

If you want to append a comment to the first line regardless if it is empty,
then you can do something like:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.py :norm ggA # your comment here
```

But this would add the comment a second time if you open the file again...